# Why stack uses List interface java collection

Tags: java

This defining property of stacks is called "Last In, First Out," or LIFO

considering the following snippet of the code

```
Stack<String> theStack = new Stack<String>();
theStack.push ("A");
theStack.push ("B");
theStack.push ("C");
theStack.remove  (1);    // removes B
```

print the output

```
System.out.println(theStack);
```

produces the output

```
[A, C]
```

Since **Stack** is part of List interface the **remove** method is available,

> "hence it violates the LIFO property of the stack"

Is this purposefully designed in Java collection Framework ?

Comment: This is a consequence of how Java has set up its Collections into List, Set, and Map

Comment: A stack is a list that implements limited access to the list elements.

Comment: A class does not necessarily need to be designed to prevent you from "abusing" it's "pure" purposes.  There are situations where it's convenient to have a stack, but it's also convenient to be able to "sleight-of-hand" the adding or removing of entries below the top.  Plus it's convenient to be able to reuse tools that display and debug a list for displaying/debugging a stack.  If you don't think the *remove* method should be used, don't use it.

Comment: I agree with your statement. They should have used a list (composition) and not extended a list/Vector

Comment: `Stack` is a old class and when it was created there was no `List` interface. It's seems to be a mistake and not a design. At the beginning of OOP inhteritance was often used to get features from other classes. However, this turned out to be wrong.

Comment: A better phrasing would be `Can a Baseclass restrict its methods from using, based on who subclasses it ?` In this case `Vector` should say "No Remove for you"  `Stack` as soon as it sees  `Stack<E> extends Vector<E>`

Comment: @Thinkingcap What if I assign a `Stack` to a variable of type `List`?

Comment: In that case, `List` will only be able to access `Stack operations`(Dynamic method dispatch)

Comment: AFAIK if you want to use a stack through interfaces you should use [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) which is a double ended queue. This means it behaves as both stack and queue, depending on the methods you use.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful in lots of ways if `Stack` implements `List`: it means that it can be used in places where a `List` is required.

But if you're using it as a stack, then you're obliged to do sensible stack-like operations on it, and that includes not arbitrarily yanking things out from the middle.

That doesn't mean it's a bad implementation of a LIFO queue, it just means that you have to be careful to use it in a LIFO fashion.

(That said, a strong case could be made for having `Stack.remove()` throw an `OperationNotSupportedException`.)

Comment: I am still not convinced :), wont it be a good approach to throw an exception when remove method is overridden, say illegaloperation(something like that)?

Comment: @zerocool Yes, I agree it would make sense for it to do that.

Comment: Doesn't that also mean that `Plane` should implement `Car` so you can drive on a regular street?

Comment: I think it should have used a List and not inherited from it.

Comment: @Chip -- OK, you're right -- they should never have implemented Stack at all -- if you want it, implement it yourself.  After all, it's easy to implement -- you just take a List and wrap it with `push` and `pop`....

Comment: @chiastic-security This is actually quite curious. From a design perspective if a class implements an interface, it has to implement all the methods and if one of the methods is not supported, the design breaks Liskov's substitution principle if it throws an exception. Think of the client that is working with the interface abstraction and suddenly to their surprise, a class that implements the interface doesn't support one of its functionalities!?

Comment: Just because it's simple to implement doesn't mean that it shouldn't be in the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Not all collections designed in java framework adhere to there algorithmic counter part. For e.g. Queue is FIFO but it is implemented by LinkedList(because linked list implements Queue interface), so you can do things which you don't expect a queue to do(like removing element from specified position, null insertion etc). If you want to create the API for strictly defining algorithmic operations, then : 
1. create you own class and back them by java classes
2. Be conscious when you are coding, and don't call irrelevant methods.

Comment: Queue is a interface, Stack not. LinkedList allows more operations because it implements multiple interfaces.

Comment: Yeap but i am referring to the general fact about the behavior of collection in respect to algorithmic design

Comment: If you get a queue as a parameter you can only call methods defined by queue. A parameter of type Stack can't be restricted to methods of a stack.

Comment: Queue is an interface and operation depends on the implementation classes for e.g. LinkedList allows null insertion but ArrayDeque will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: Allowing null has nothing to do with LIFO/FIFO.

Comment: Read Api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html  and think about capacity restricted queue.

Comment: It's already defined in the interface. Therefore an queue with fixed capacity doesn't violates the Liskov's substitution principle.

Comment: Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>(); Object obj = null; queue.add(obj). According to algorithmic aspect of queue, i will expect it to be invalid but according to java it's valid and will not report as error.

Comment: Why shouldn't be null allowed?